# Is there a way to delete the PDF byte array and html file?

Tags: java, file, writer

I'm trying to delete the byte array PDF and HTML file after it has been generated and the PDF is saved to a byte array Document to save server space usage. The Writer class and the pdf byte array do not have the delete methods. Appreciate it if anyone can help me out with this.

```java
// File output
Writer file = new FileWriter (new File("src/" + "xyz.html"));
template.process(data, file);
file.flush();
file.close();

HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream("src/" + "xyz.html"),new FileOutputStream("src/" + "XYZ.pdf"));

Path pdfPath = Paths.get("src/" + "XYZ.pdf");
byte[] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);

byteDocument = pdf;
 
//Delete pdf and html files.
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything to delete them.  If you stop using them, the garbage collector will get rid of them.  Java doesn't have or need delete methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough RAM to hold the PDF, it's likely you have enough for the source HTML at the same time. In that case, skip the file system altogether:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(buffer);
template.process(data, writer);
writer.flush();

ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray());
buffer.reset();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(input, buffer);

byteDocument = buffer.toByteArray();
```

If you need to use the file system due to memory constraints, use [`Files.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) to remove your temporary files.

Comment: Thanks, I used Files.delete() to remove the temp files